# Do I need a visa to transfer from Haneda airport to Narita airport?

Tags: visas, airport-transfer

I am planning to fly from China to the USA. One of the optiona is from Beijing to Haneda and then Narita to the USA? Do I need a Japanese visa for this transfer with my Chinese passport?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You're going to need a double-entry transit visa (assuming your return flights are the same in reverse).

To go from Haneda to Narita you need to pass through Immigration, and thus, as a Chinese citizen, need a visa. You'll also have to take care of the luggage yourself.

Comment: same question here. how and where to get the transit visa? also how about the luggage? The JAL will take care of the luggage from one airport to another?